# create a calculated column in sql combining text and a substring of another column

Tags: sql, calculated-columns

I have a column called TAG_ that can be any of the following

```
XV-123451
YV-123452
STV-123453
```

I want to create a calculated column that puts ZSC- plus all the characters after the hyphen.

From a previous question I have asked on here, the way to get all the characters after the hyphen is:

```
SUBSTRING(TAG_ ,CHARINDEX('-',TAG_ ,0)+1,LEN(TAG_ ))
```

How do I add to the formula above to put ZSC- in front of it?

The answers I'm looking for are as follows:

```
ZSC-123451
ZSC-123452
ZSC-123453
```

This should be easy but I don't have the time to spend in SQL like I should with my job duties.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: String processing functions vary from dbms to dbms. MySQL does it differently from Oracle, which does it differently from PostgreSQL, which does it differently from SQL Server, which does it differently from SQLite, and so on, and so on...  That said, most support `CONCAT(string1, string2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On SQL Server we can try:

```sql
ALTER TABLE yourTable
ADD NEW_TAG AS ('ZSC' + SUBSTRING(TAG_, CHARINDEX('-', TAG_) + 1, LEN(TAG_)));
```

Comment: Wouldn't `STUFF()` be better for SQL Server?

Comment: @MatBailie I'm not too sure about database stuff.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/CsfQkM6w *(`STUFF()` effectively doing the job of three parts; the `SUBSTRING()` and the `LEN()` and the concatenation...)*

Answer (score 0):

On mysql you can do it as follows :

```
select Tag, CONCAT('ZSC-', SUBSTRING_INDEX(Tag,'-',-1)) AS new_tag
from table1;
```

[demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7P11Lr3J)

Comment: The OP is likely using SQL Server.